# Multiple parsers for keywords in strings

Tags: python, strings, parsing

I'm writing some code that parses strings, often using simple keywords. On parsing, the code performs various actions, such a printing a response, running functions etc. and it keeps track of whether it was able to respond.

I am actually using multiple parsers and have illustrated this in the code shown below.

What would be better ways to structure this code, particularly with a mind to scalability and code compactness? For example, imagine many more parsers being added that operate on principles more complex than simple keyword-spotting.

MWE:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import json
import os
import requests
import subprocess
import sys

def main():

    message = "how are you"
    #message = "ip address"
    #message = "restart"

    triggered = [
        parse_1(message = message),
        parse_2(message = message)
    ]

    if not any(triggered):

        report_help()

def parse_1(
    message = None
    ):

    def keyphrases_text_response(
        message    = None,
        keyphrases = None,
        response   = None
        ):

        if any(pattern in message for pattern in keyphrases):

            print(response)

            return True

        else:

            return False

    triggered = [
        keyphrases_text_response(
            message    = message,
            keyphrases = [
                        "image"
                        ],
            response   = "http://i.imgur.com/MiqrlTh.jpg"
        ),
        keyphrases_text_response(
            message    = message,
            keyphrases = [
                        "sup",
                        "hi"
                        ],
            response   = "sup home bean"
        ),
        keyphrases_text_response(
            message    = message,
            keyphrases = [
                        "how are you",
                        "are you well",
                        "status"
                        ],
            response   = "nae bad fam"
        ),
        keyphrases_text_response(
            message    = message,
            keyphrases = [
                        "help",
                        "what can you do"
                        ],
            response   = "I can report my IP address and I can restart my script."
        )
    ]

    if any(triggered):

        return True

    else:

        return False

def parse_2(
    message = None
    ):

    triggered = []

    if any(pattern in message for pattern in\
        [
            "IP",
            "I.P.",
            "IP address",
            "I.P. address",
            "ip address"
        ]
        ):

        triggered.append(True)
        report_IP()

    if any(pattern in message for pattern in\
        [
            "restart"
        ]
        ):

        triggered.append(True)
        restart()

    if any(pattern in message for pattern in\
        [
            "SSH",
            "reverse"
        ]
        ):

        triggered.append(True)
        engage_command(
            command    = "ssh -R 10000:localhost:22 www.sern.ch",
            background = True
        )

    if any(triggered):

        return True

    else:

        return False

def report_IP(
    contact = None,
    country = True
    ):

    IP = "unknown"

    try:

        data_IP_website = requests.get("http://ipinfo.io/json")
        data_IP         = data_IP_website.json()
        IP              = data_IP["ip"]
        country         = data_IP["country"]

    except:

        pass

    text = "IP address: " + IP

    if country:

        text = text + " (" + country + ")"

    print(text)

def restart():

    print("restart! (and I'm in a crazy loop!)")
    import __main__
    os.execv(__main__.__file__, sys.argv)

def report_help():

    print("I can report my IP address, I can restart my script and I can run commands.")

def engage_command(
    command    = None,
    background = False
    ):

    print("engage command: {command}".format(command = command))

    if not background:

        process = subprocess.Popen(
            [command],
            shell      = True,
            executable = "/bin/bash"
        )
        process.wait()
        output, errors = process.communicate()

        return output

    else:

        subprocess.Popen(
            [command],
            shell      = True,
            executable = "/bin/bash"
        )

        return None

if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

Comment: I'd recommend checking out [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and [flake8](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/) to help improve readability of your code.